# CMake multiline generator expressions

Tags: cmake

How can I use multiline generator expressions? For example transforming this:

```
target_include_directories(application-smth
PRIVATE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/application-smth>
PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)
```

to this

```
target_include_directories(application-smth
PRIVATE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data>
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/application-smth>
    >
PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)
```

makes /include/application-smth folder headers not available

Comment: Every generator expression eventually produces at most one argument. This is why your second snippet is incorrect. The exception is only for generator expressions which extract value of multi-values properties: such expressions could be evaluated to the several arguments. Assuming you have a list of include directories in a variable, you could append `BUILD_INTERFACE` to every such directory by using `list(TRANSFORM <list> REPLACE)`.

Comment: Your snippet just incorrect... you forget to remove `>`  after paths. Also, try to write the `BUILD_INTERFACE` genex at one line and put `;` (list items delimiter) between paths.

Comment: @Tsyvarev please elaborate or point to documentation why "Every generator expression eventually produces at most one argument" I do bought Professional CMake: A Practical Guide and didnt found anything about it

Comment: You don't even need "Professional CMake" to learn that this won't work. Read [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#whitespace-and-quoting): "_A common mistake is to try to split a generator expression across multiple lines with indenting. New lines and spaces all treated as argument separators, so the generator expression is split and not recognized correctly \[...\] Again, use helper variables with well-chosen names to build up a readable expression instead._"